# CSS keyframes: multiple frames smooth transitions

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the following keyframe, the problem is that, the animation is not smooth, it stops at 50%, and then goes to 100%. Is there any way to make multiple frames behave like one?

```
@keyframes orbit_moveY {
  0% {
    top: -4px;
  }

  50% {
    top: 2px;
  }

  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Also, the code for the animation is the following:
`animation: orbit_moveY 2s linear 0s infinite normal`.

edit: the final objective would be the ball to go through this:
https://d.pr/FREE/CPxkRR , from right to left, without stoping in the middle (50% on the keyframe)... Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/zRRPew)

Comment: the problem is that i need to make an X change too. Also, using translate3d we might get more fps's right? I want it to make a curved path, around a circunference, 180 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *(not sure at 100%)* this is a matter of calculation. You may notice that you are using very close values (`-4px`, `0px`, `2px`). So you have **4px** difference between 0% and 50% and only **2px** between 50% and 100%. I don't know what is the exact presicion of browser but due to some rounding you will have similar value around the 50% which create this effect of **stops**.

Let's suppose that the calculated values are as follow:

```
-4 -3.9 -3.8 -3.7 .....  1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 (2) 1.9 1.8 1.7 .... 0.2 0.1 0
```

After some rounding you may endup with something like this around the value of 2

```
... 1.5 1.6 2 2 2 (2) 2 2 2 1.6 ...
```

So the same value will be repeated and used many times which create this effect.

Here is the same example with a big value of duration where we can see this clearly

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  animation: orbit_moveY 8s 0s infinite;
}


@keyframes orbit_moveY {
  0% {
    top: -4px;
  }

  50% {
    top: 2px;
  }

  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is not the bump after the animation ends. It's in between...It goes from 0% to 50%..then stops for a few miliseconds then proceeds to 100%...I want it to behave like a single motion

Comment: @JoãoVilaça because of the linear :) i will explain this in my answer ;)

Comment: im using `animation: orbit_moveY 2s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .2, 1) 0s infinite normal;` and still stops at 50%

Comment: @JoãoVilaça am adding an explanation :) give me 5 min ;)

Comment: I will try and post a gif too, to help visualize what im trying to say lol, sorry and thank you!

Comment: here: https://d.pr/FREE/OtvmWs , dont mind the fps, its running smoothly on my end. As u can see, its a curved path, and the ball stops at the middle (50% keyframe), which is not the intended behaviour

Comment: @JoãoVilaça well, i see it not the same animation .. but it's good if you can share its code :) by they way i added an explanation on how i think it works

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `top:` values are too low. May be you should give them bigger values like 100px and start from `0%` to `100%`:

```
@keyframes orbit_moveY {
  0% {
    top: -4px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100px;
  }
}
```